# ASP.NET Validator Issue when setting Display ="Dynamic"

Tags: asp.net

Here is my ASP.NET code. Simple. it has a A textbox associated with a required field validator and a submit button.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="Dynamic" 
        ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  Text="Click Me" />
```

Do the following

1. Click on Button1
2. RequiredFieldValidator will be shown
3. Type some text in TextBox
4. Use your Mouse(no tab please). and click on the button , you can see that your page does not "POSTBACK" and only the validation gets cleared. you need to

click again the button for Submission of Form.

This seems to be  a bug by Microsoft when setting the property Display ="Dynmaic" and Is there a easy workaround without changing the intended behavior for

this available? I couldn't find a solution for this anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your page does not submit because the button moves away under the mouse when you want to click it. This is because it gets focus and the Validator-ErrorMessage disappears to the left. 
If you insert a `<br/>` in front of the button it works.

Normally i use * as Text and use a [ValidationSummary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd5c6s6h%28VS.71%29.aspx) to display the ErrorMessage(s):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="Dynamic" 
        ErrorMessage="This is the Errormessage" Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
```

Or, if using ASP.Net Ajax, you could use nifty controls like the [ValidatorCalloutExtender](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2008/06/validatorcalloutextender-ajax-control.html).

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the reply. adding a break tag helped. Great to see a valuable reply. Now, I need to try out in the project code something similar, in which I might have some trouble in doing the same

Comment: When you can't place a button after the validator, you can use css style min-height to set the size of the table and the button outside the table, it will not moving. :)