# ASP.NET Validator Issue when setting Display =“Dynamic”

Tags: asp.net, validation, dynamic, display

We recently upgraded our application from .Net 2/vs 2005 to .net 4.5/vs2012 and are seeing exactly same issue noted in [ASP.NET Validator Issue when setting Display ="Dynamic"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468938/asp-net-validator-issue-when-setting-display-dynamic/37400699#37400699) this question. My submit button moves down on validation failure and we have to double click to trigger postback. Adding `<br />` before submit button is not acceptable solution for us as we have over 200 pages. Is there any generic solution to this problem.

below is the code snippet:

`<asp:textbox id="txtCancellationDays" runat="server" maxlength="3"/>
    <asp:rangevalidator id="rvCancelDays" runat="server" controltovalidate="txtCancellationDays"
        maximumvalue="999" minimumvalue="0" type="Integer" text="Cancellation cutoff days must be a number between 0 and 999." />
    <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="rfvCancelDays" runat="server" display="Dynamic" controltovalidate="txtCancellationDays"
        text="Cancellation Cutoff Days is required" />
    <asp:comparevalidator id="cvCancelDays" text="Cancel Days must be less than or equal to Waitlist Days"
        runat="server" controltovalidate="txtCancellationDays" controltocompare="txtWaitlistDays" type="Integer"
        operator="LessThanEqual" />`

Comment: Can you show us the markup of the TextBox, the validator and the button, along with their container? If you use `Display="Dynamic"`, and if the button element is next to the validator, then it will move to the right or to the next line. Is one better than the other? Moving to the right can cause trouble too. If the indicator is short (e.g. `*`), you could use `Display="Static"`.

Comment: I have a textbox with Required, Range and Comaper validators. All the controls are in fieldset. Button is not moving left/right but is moving down. Using Static is not an option for us.

Comment: Can you put that markup in the question? I must have it to test any suggestion that I could make.

Comment: Any thoughts or suggestions otherthan changing display from dynamic to static??

Comment: I don't see, in the markup shown above, what forces a button to go to the next line. Are these controls in a `div` container? You could show the container of these elements, along with the button. From your markup, I just assume that the validator text would show up at the right of the TextBox. (By the way, you can use the "Code sample" tool of the editor; you don't need to HTML-encode it.)

Comment: It doesn't matter where i place these controls. I used table, div and also fieldset. I added hack to see what is causing the problem and it is ValidatorOnChange. I added javascript to set onchange on textbox to null and things started to work..But this is NOT the solution.